# Get order title(s) in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I'm trying to get the names of the ordered products through my functions.php file with a loop. Heres's my code:

```
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
    $_product = $values['data']->post; 
}
```

And then i call the title like this:

```
$_product->post_title
```

This works, it returns me the name of the product I ordered. The thing is when i have 2 or more products it still returns me 1 name. How can i make it so it returns all the names in the cart.

Comment: Are you checking the title inside the foreach loop? It's not clear in your example.

Comment: now what to do you want to do next??

Comment: I think this is solved

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get ALL woocommerce cart item names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039837/get-all-woocommerce-cart-item-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new syntax in woocommerce relative to cart is made with **`WC()`** without any need of calling **`global woocommerce;`**

So your code will be this:

```
$products_in_cart= array();
$products_post_title_in_cart = array();
$products_ids_in_cart= array();

foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
    $products_in_cart[] = $cart_item['data']->post;
    $products_post_title_in_cart[] = $cart_item['data']->post->post_title;
    $products_ids_in_cart[] = $cart_item['product_id'];
}

// The first product (or item of the cart)
$_product = $products_in_cart[0]; // product post data
$product_id = $products_ids_in_cart[0]; // product ID
$products_post_title_in_cart[0] // product post title

// The Second product (or item of the cart)
$_product = $products_in_cart[1]; // product post data
$product_id = $products_ids_in_cart[1]; // product ID
$products_post_title_in_cart[1] // product post title

// etc … for all other products you increase the key of the arrays to get the correct values
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.I am intermediate level.

Comment: @VasimVanzara I am not answering you anyway… this has nothing to do with level… Everyone can answer without level considerations or not?

Comment: When i add 2 products to the cart it returns only 1 product

Comment: @Kevin.a this is normal as you need something else for the second product… I update my answer

Comment: @Kevin.a Updated my answer … as it's a foreach loop it goes through each item in cart… if you have 10 items, you will have to increase the key value of the arrays to get the correct data. This key value is `0` for the first item, `1` for the second one  and so on …

Comment: Please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039837/get-all-woocommerce-cart-item-names?noredirect=1#comment69286983_41039837

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    $arr_product=array();
        foreach($items as $item => $values) {             
           $arr_product[]= $_product->post_title;            
        } 
    print_r($arr_product,true); // echo print_r(); thats why get 1
?>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. But i need to call $_product['my_post']->post_title; outside the for loop

Comment: It still returns 1 item name if i add 2 it returns 1

Comment: global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
print_r($items);exit;

Comment: can you paste that array in your question

Comment: it returns a number the number is 1

Comment: I get list of cart product here.please check updated code

Comment: I still get the number 1  :\

Comment: print_r($items, true) Please use this.

Comment: or you can use this echo implode(" ",$items);

Comment: Array(    [0] => Dexport social media campagne    [1] => Dexport social media campagne) i get this now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130105/discussion-between-kevin-a-and-vasim-vanzara).

Comment: i can not use echo

Comment: yes that what i say.It attached from some where else

Comment: If you want to list of product implode(" ",$items);

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039837/get-all-woocommerce-cart-item-names?noredirect=1#comment69286983_41039837

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code, Its returns all the names in the cart.**

```
global $woocommerce; 

$cart_item = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart(); 

echo "<pre>";
print_r($cart_item);

exit();
```